# Why does Jobs recommend entering a name for each project?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have two projects in [my CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/yoh.deadfall). They have synchronised their names and descriptions with GitHub, but the site recommends I fill in these fields by myself to improve the CV.

Why isn't synchronised information counted in the Completion Score?

Comment: The completion score is known to require far too many special cases; I’d recommend you to simply ignore it unfortunately :/

Comment: It's a *completion score*, it doesn't mean anything. Same with all the other sites that have them: they're just a gimmick to try to get you to push a little harder, not some minimum threshold you *must* meet to do things right.

Comment: @Nathan, these fields may not be counted in the score, but the recommendation to fill them discourages. It's like somebody asks you and doesn't listen to your answer.